# angular-fullstack openshift deployment

Tags: angularjs, openshift, angular-fullstack

generator-angular-fullstack documentation for openshift deployment (http://angular-fullstack.github.io/generator-angular-fullstack/Generators/openshift.html) says we should take measures to ensure we are using up to date release of nodejs on openshift.  Helpfully, a link is provided to a sample project that does just that.  Its accomplished by putting a marker file and some scripts in a ".openshift" directory at the root of the app that gets deployed to Openshift.

All good, but how to accomplish that with the build flow the generator users?  I could put the .openshift stuff in my project but that feels wrong and the generator doesnt include that directory in the copy to dist out of the box.

Should I put the .openshift stuff right in the dist directory manually?  What is best practice here?